# Failed to do runtime upgrade: FailedToExtractRuntimeVersion

Tags: runtime, runtime-upgrade

When trying to migrate the runtime from a very early version of `substrate 3 (aug 2021)` to `polkadot 0.9.18` we are getting the following error:

```
 Failed to extract the runtime version from the new runtime., ,  Either calling `Core_version` or decoding `RuntimeVersion` failed.
```

Following RuntimeVersion struct was defined:

```
pub const VERSION: RuntimeVersion = RuntimeVersion {
    spec_name: create_runtime_str!("substrate-threefold"),
    impl_name: create_runtime_str!("substrate-threefold"),
    authoring_version: 1,
    // The version of the runtime specification. A full node will not attempt to use its native
    //   runtime in substitute for the on-chain Wasm runtime unless all of `spec_name`,
    //   `spec_version`, and `authoring_version` are the same between Wasm and native.
    // This value is set to 100 to notify Polkadot-JS App (https://polkadot.js.org/apps) to use
    //   the compatible custom types.
    spec_version: 100,
    impl_version: 1,
    apis: RUNTIME_API_VERSIONS,
    transaction_version: 2,
    state_version: 0,
};
```

I read that `state_version` should be set to 0 in order to perform the migration. But it seems like it's not working.

Comment: can you elaborate more

Answer (score 1):

We faced this issue before, how we solved it was by using the correct rust version (including nightly) that the version of polkadot/substrate you are referencing in your Cargo.toml

You can have a look at the release [notes](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.43) because it shows you what version a particular release was built with